# Scala^Z3 kills running Thread on parser error

Tags: scala, z3

When I use Scala^Z3 (Z3 3.2 and according Scala^Z3 java library) and get a parser error like:

```
(error "line 21 column 41: invalid command, '(' expected")
Error: parser error
```

The executed Thread is killed and I cannot stop this by surrounding
the code with try/catch or anything.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is not much to do: there is supposedly a call to `exit` in the Z3 library, and that is what causes this behavior.

As far as I understand the Java Native Interface, I cannot prevent the native function from terminating the process. The best I could do is add an exit hook to the JVM that could warn the user that the program is terminating due to external reasons, but that won't let you resume where you were in the control flow.

The ideal solution is of course that Z3 is updated so that no function in the public interface ever calls `exit`.

Comment: This is not so good. Even threading won't help here... the whole process is exited... Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Philippe: this is a good point. This will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem. It seems Scala^Z3 is not setting an error handler for Z3. The default error handler just prints the message `Error: <msg>`, and aborts. One can set the error handler by using the function `Z3_set_error_handler`. For example, the OCaml wrapper sets an error handler that throws an exception (file: `ocaml/z3_stubs.c` in the Z3 distribution).

Comment: Hmmm there's a slight complication; since C function pointer addresses are resolved at compile-time, I cannot create one error handler per context. The workaround would be to create a single one that acts as a dynamic dispatcher (this is what I did for theory callbacks, for instance). Now the problem is, error callbacks just take the error code as an argument, not the Z3_context in which the error occurred, so there would be no (clean) way for the dispatcher to know where to forward the error.

Comment: I looked at the OCaml version, and there's apparently only one error handler. This seems to work because `failwith` can be directly invoked from the C code that is linked with the OCaml program. To achieve the equivalent with the Java Native Interface, I need at least a reference to the virtual machine, which I can only recover if I know in which context the error occurred. Any chance the callback type can be extended? Perhaps a new callback type `typedef void Z3_context_error_handler(Z3_context ctx, Z3_error_code e)` could do the tricK?